# Is it possible to create circle arrow icon in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-shapes

I want to crate a circle arrow icon like blew picture. Is it possible animate it around of circle icon?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate image of arrow with css animation:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```